# Android to download a Zip file

Tags: android, visual-studio, file, download, zip

I'm trying to download a zip file from an API. For this purpose I'm using this following code:

```
public class Download_Activity extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download);
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = downloadURL;
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            Log.i("1111", "1111" );
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "hello1.zip");
            Log.i("2222", "2222" );
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            int downloadedSize = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            Log.i("3333", "3333" );
            Log.i("befferLength", "bufferLength: " + bufferLength);
            Log.i("is read buffer", "is read buffer: " + inputStream.read(buffer));
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                Log.i("inside while", "inside while ");
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
            }
            Log.i("4444", "4444" );
            fileOutput.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;


    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}

public void updateProgress(int currentSize, int totalSize) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading Files...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In this code, the zip file is created as "hello1.zip" but this file is empty in my mobile. Here I've various log statements to find the execution of code. To my surprise only upto "Log.i("2222", "2222" );" is printed while the rest of the logs are not printed. Can you please tell me what the problem is???

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: add some log in the `catch` and see if you get an exception

Answer (score 0):

U can use DownloadManager class for this purpose it handles the pause and continues the dowloading in the case of network availablity and you can run a broadcast reciver to perform you actions( like pushing a notification etc) when dowloading is complete
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html